# (c++) How to find the last character in a std::string from a specific (end) point?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to extract specific elements of a html-form to perform a html-post with theses fields. first of all a short example form:

```
<form>
  <input name="field1">
  <input name="field2">
</form>
```

now i am trying to get the whole input-tag (field2):

```
ptr = form.find("name=\"field2\"")
end = form.find(">", ptr)+1;
```

the thing is i want to find the start position of that tag (the last "<" character before *ptr*). I thought about string::rfind but I can't figure a smart way out  to use it in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what [`rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) is for - you just give it what you're looking for (`'<'`) and where to start counting backwards from (`ptr`):

```
size_t last_open = form.rfind('<', ptr);
```

Comment: oh i see... there was somethin else wrong in my code... stupid question. thanks!